# Turning Flutter Arguments into Usable Variables on another dart file

Tags: flutter

My final goal is to have a **userName variable** from one dart file transferred to the other dart file.

Firebase Authentication will only take the email and password inputs so **I need to pass the **userName variable** as an argument into another file** that is called after the users email has been verified.

I have been trying to find videos and documentation online, most of what I found is trying to put the data into a list (which I would like to avoid).  I don't understand the "this." getter function in flutter yet, I don't know if it's necessary to solve this problem.  Let me know if there's anything I can clarify, I hope I'm overlooking something simple.

**Dart File #1**

```
onPressed: () => signUp(_email, _password).then((_) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Verify(_userName)));
}),
```

**Dart File #2**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Verify extends StatefulWidget {
  const Verify(String _userName, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VerifyState createState() => _VerifyState();
}

class _VerifyState extends State<Verify> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:
            Text('Here is your variable $_userName please verify'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you can skip the verify part and just create the database with the username and all, and when a user is trying to login, just check if the email is verified if yes then let him login, else display an error saying you haven't verified your email.

Comment: I don't want to save the password to the firestore database.  That could potentially work if I could hash the password or remove it later.  I still want to know how to pass arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. You're asking how to pass arguments to a widget? Also, what's the `.this` function?

Comment: The two pieces of code in this question are on two different .dart files.
I would like to take the _userName variable from one document and use it on the other.  

Also the this. function has it's own question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324559/what-does-mean-of-using-the-this-keyword-in-dart

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; is the issue that you don't know how to write data to Firestore (which is covered in the getting started guide) or that you don't know how to pass data between classes or something else entirely? You code also includes a timer and a number of other things that seem unrelated to whatever the question is. Can you clarify what's being asked? Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I modified the question to be more concise.  Please review it again, and let me know If I can clarify further.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're asking about passing arguments(any object) between different screens.
You can do this easily by passing it in RouteSettings, you can pass any object (String, int, map) and then fetch it in the build method of another Screen.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextButton(
    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
    context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => HomeScreen(), 
      settings: const RouteSettings(arguments: 'username')),), //arguments
    child: Text('Hello, World!', 
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    ),
  );
}
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String; //arguments
  return TextButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text(args, 
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    ),
  );
}
}
```